# Private instance variable in servlet set to null?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, servlets, servlet-listeners

In my servlet I start a background thread `onContextInitialized()` and consequently I need to stop it `onContextDestroyed()`. So my servlet needs a private instance variable (let's call this `daemon`) pointing to this daemon thread.
The daemon runs fine, but the reference is lost as soon as I exit `contextInitialized()`! For example, if I implement `doGet()` to show the status of the thread, it throws a NPE

So the answer is, who can access my servlet private instance variable and set it to null?
I remark that the thread runs just fine, just the reference is broken

Comment: Can you put up the code of onContextInitialized? This sounds rather peculiar. Could it be, that the instance variable is shadowed, because you declare a similar named local variable in onContextInitialized?

Comment: No, it seems to me that the servlet object is destroyed after contextInitialized() executes. Quite difficult to understand why..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the reference in Application Context or set it to some static field of some class[less preferable]

Not sure what you want to achieve but this will do

Comment: Thanks, this is just what the doc says :)

Comment: However I don't understand why the servlet object is destroyed in Tomcat after contextInitialized() is called...

Comment: I don't understand `However I don't understand why the servlet object is destroyed in Tomcat after contextInitialized() is called...` put the code if you want to clear that doubt up

Comment: Sorry, I can't post my code since I have no access to it right now and for the weekend. Anyway it's quite minimal: a simple servlet implementing ServletContextListener

Answer (score 1):

Make it `static` so all instances can see it:

```
private static Thread daemon;
```

Comment: AFAIK this should not be required, since Tomcat initalizes the servlet and then refers to that very instance object

Comment: @Raggaele you're right, it shouldn't be necesarry in most Servlet containers. Please, if you can, post your code.

Comment: Setting it static makes the trick. However I prefer the @Jigar Joshi answer, since it's just what the official doc states (ie, using ServletContext.setAttribute())